# Display lunar calendar using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, calendar

I have to display lunar calendar using JavaScript. I tried to use -

1. [jqueryui localization](https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/localization.html), but it's just translating calendar into Chinese language
2. Then I came across [this](http://www.javascriptbank.com/lunar-calendar-script-index.html), but it's displaying both Lunar and English calendar
3. I also have gone through http://www.html5tricks.com/jquery-lunar-calendar.html, but looks like it's just translating English calendar into Chinese.

   How to display Lunar Calender using JS? Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I end up using http://www.javascriptbank.com/lunar-calendar-script-index.html
link and made some CSS changes.